# Automating the Compilation of Dependent Python Scripts into a Stand-Alone Script

Tags: python, python-3.x

As an illustration, consider the scenario where attempting to run a Python script, like LaZagne.py, as a standalone file fails due to heavy dependencies on other scripts within the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/AlessandroZ/LaZagne/). Is there an automated method or tool that can amalgamate these scripts into a single stand-alone Python script? While I'm aware of pyinstaller, it generates an executable, and my specific requirement is for a stand-alone Python script. Are there alternative solutions or approaches to achieve this for scripts that rely on another scripts?